# How to display an array using ion-select and ion-option?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to display an array using `<ion-select>` and `<ion-option>`, the following code however is not working:

**home.ts**

```
cars=['BMW','Ferari','Audi','Bugati'];
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-select>CARS</ion-select>
<ion-option>{{cars}}</ion-option>
```

Comment: is this angularjs or angular

Comment: I am trying in ionic with angular J's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like below:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Employee</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="employee" [compareWith]="compareFn">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee"></ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

For more informaton, see [Ionic API Documentation - select](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/)

Comment: Im using formControlname instead of ngmodel its not working